# Customizing MapBox Marker with Label

Tags: android, mapbox

So far it seems like the API is limited to just being able to change the icon, but it would be nice if you could define a layout file or add a label above the icon that shows the title for instance, instead of requiring a tap interaction to show the info window. It's possible with Google Maps to define a layout and use that to create a cluster item to achieve this, but is it possible with MapBox since it is based on Mapbox GL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish using Mapbox, bubble icons? They take in a string (in the image it is a price) and creates a bitmap icon for you to use as a marker icon.

I'll edit my answer with code if this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way you can add an icon below the text window? If so, then yes, that is what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Comment: I'm sure you could include an icon within the bitmap. Markers already have info windows that appear above on a click and will display a title for instance. The difference I assume is that you want all the Markers on you map to just show their info window constantly and at the same time without the user having to click on them?

Comment: Yes, for this particular example at least, but also interested in the limitations in general if you could elaborate a little more on that. Marking as correct answer nonetheless.

Comment: @cammace could you please share code to achieve marker image with custom text inside. I am trying to make something similiar but struggling with some issues. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the Bubble annotation inside the Map SDK 6.0.1. This should give you the same effect.

Comment: can we get any sample code on this particular testapp??